# Unity Editor Mode - How do I get OnHierarchyChange to repaint the scene when children are added/deleted to the object the script is on?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

Have script which runs in [ExecuteAlways] mode. It is mainly a function called at Start() and OnValidate() to update the position of objects based on changes in an Editor. This all works fine.

When an object is added as a child to the object with the script in the Hierarchy window I want UpdateRing() to be called and integrate that into the ring. Putting OnHierarchyChange() with UpdateRing() doesn't seem to do anything. In other questions OnHierarchyChange() is put in the Editor file but I don't know how I can put OnHierarchyChange() in the Editor file and call UpdateRing()...or if that is even something I should do...

**GameObject Code:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

[Serializable]
[ExecuteAlways]
public class ObjectsRing : MonoBehaviour
{
//public float radius = { get { return m_Radius; } set { m_Radius = value; } }
[Range(0f, 100f)]
public float radius = 10;

[Range(0f,360f)]
public float beginAngle = 0f;

[Range(0f,360f)]
public float endAngle = 360f;

public bool flip = false;

public enum orientationList {[Description("X-up")] Xup, [Description("Y-up")] Yup, [Description("Z-up")] Zup};

public orientationList orientation;    

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    UpdateRing();
}

// OnValidate is called when fields are changed in an Editor
void OnValidate()
{
    UpdateRing();       
}

// OnHierarchyChange is called when changes are made in the Hierarchy pane. 
void OnHierarchyChange()
{
    UpdateRing();  
}

private void UpdateRing()
{
    //Input error handling
    if (endAngle < beginAngle)
    {
        float tempAngle = beginAngle; 
        beginAngle = endAngle;
        endAngle = tempAngle;
    }

    // Attach mesh, rotate object and add material
    float objectAngle = (endAngle - beginAngle) / (transform.childCount);
    float rotation = beginAngle;
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < transform.childCount; cnt++)
    {
        // Translate and rotate each object
        transform.GetChild(cnt).GetComponent<Transform>().localPosition = new Vector3(radius, 0, 0);
        // transform.GetChild(cnt).GetComponent<Transform>().rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotation, 0);
        rotation = beginAngle + cnt * objectAngle;
        transform.GetChild(cnt).RotateAround(transform.position, new Vector3(0,1,0), rotation);
        transform.GetChild(cnt).LookAt(transform.position);
        if (flip)
            {
            transform.GetChild(cnt).Rotate(new Vector3(0,180,0));
        }
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case orientationList.Xup:
                {
                    transform.GetChild(cnt).Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,0));
                    break;                
                }         
                case orientationList.Yup:
                {
                    transform.GetChild(cnt).Rotate(new Vector3(90,0,0));
                    break;                
                }         
                case orientationList.Zup:
                {
                    transform.GetChild(cnt).Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,90));
                    break;                
                }                  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Editor Code:**

```
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ObjectsRing)), CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class ObjectsRingEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty radiusProperty;
    private SerializedProperty beginAngleProperty;
    private SerializedProperty endAngleProperty;
    private SerializedProperty flipProperty;
    private SerializedProperty orientationProperty;

    public void OnEnable()
    {
        radiusProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("radius");
        beginAngleProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("beginAngle");
        endAngleProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("endAngle");
        flipProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("flip");
        orientationProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("orientation");
    }


    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        radiusProperty.floatValue = EditorGUILayout.Slider ("Radius", radiusProperty.floatValue, 0, 100);
        beginAngleProperty.floatValue = EditorGUILayout.Slider ("Begin Angle", beginAngleProperty.floatValue, 0, 360);
        endAngleProperty.floatValue = EditorGUILayout.Slider ("End Angle", endAngleProperty.floatValue, 0, 360);
        flipProperty.boolValue = EditorGUILayout.Toggle ("Flip", flipProperty.boolValue);
        orientationProperty.enumValueIndex = EditorGUILayout.Popup ("Orientation", orientationProperty.enumValueIndex, orientationProperty.enumDisplayNames);

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        EditorApplication.update.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in other answers [`OnHierarchyChange`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.OnHierarchyChange.html) is a message of `EditorWindow` and will only be called by Unity in this type of class, not in a `MonoBehaviour`.

---

**However, the solution is actually quite simple!**

If tagging your class [`[ExecuteAllways]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteAlways.html) or [`[ExecuteInEditMode]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html) the method in `MonoBehaviour` classes getting called if anything in the Scene changes is simply `Update`!

> `Update` is only called when something in the Scene changed.

Changing something in the hierarchy implies that also something in the scene is changed.

So you can simply put it I `Update` and only have to prevent it from running later in the build application

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void Update()
    {
        UpdateRing();
    }
#endif
```

the `#if UNITY_EDIROR` preprocessor will make sure this part is removed in a build avoiding overhead of `Update` getting called entirely.

In case you need the `Update` for something else you could alternatively also either do

```
    private void Update()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        UpdateRing();
#endif

        ...
    }
```

or also

```
private void Update()
{
    if(Application.isEditor)
    {
        UpdateRing();
    }

    ...
}
```

---

Sidenotes

- Actually what is the custom `Editor` script for? I don't see it adding anything that wouldn't be drawn in the Inspector by default anyway ...
- `[Serializable]` is redundant on a class of type `MonoBehaviour`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these interactions. Helps to understand where the edge is between the Editor and Runtime.

Answer (score 3):

[`OnHierarchyChange`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.OnHierarchyChange.html) belongs to the `EditorWindow` class and as such will only work within scripts derived from `EditorWindow`.

By using in a `Monobehaviour` script you are simply creating a new method called `OnHierarchyChange` within your script which is not associated with the Unity *message* `EditorWindow.OnHierarchyChange`.

Take a look at: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-hierarchyChanged.html

I was able to modify the example code a bit to execute within a `Monobehaviour` with `[ExecuteAlways]` attribute.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class HierarchyMonitor : MonoBehaviour
{
    static HierarchyMonitor()
    {
        EditorApplication.hierarchyChanged += OnHierarchyChanged;
    }

    static void OnHierarchyChanged()
    {
        Debug.Log("Heirarchy Has changed");
        //do you ring update here
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could modify your editor code to be an `EditorWindow` and use `EditorWindow.OnHeirarchyChange` but then you would need the window open to allow it to execute.

Comment: Thanks for the direction but can't directly call UpdateRIng() from in that function - doesn't exist in the current context. As for the alt - I want this to update whether or not the window is open. Want the ring to immediately update when a new object is added - especially since the new object will be the selection and having to click back to the parent removes the immediacy of understanding the result.

Comment: Put     

    void OnHierarchyChanged()
        {
            UpdateRing();       
        }

        void Update()
        {
            EditorApplication.hierarchyChanged += OnHierarchyChanged;
        }

In ObjectRing and it does update on changes to the hierarchy. Not sure its the best way....

Comment: I don't think that a non-static class may have a static constructor ;) especially not a one derived from `MonoBehaviour`! **But** Unity offers an alternative for this: simply make it a static method instead and tag it `[InitializeOnLoadMethod]` -> makes a static method get called when the project is loaded.

Answer (score -2):

**Put...**

```
void OnHierarchyChanged()
    { 
        UpdateRing();
    } 

void Update()
    {
        EditorApplication.hierarchyChanged += OnHierarchyChanged;
    }
```

...in the ObjectRing class and it does update immediately on changes to the hierarchy without regards the selection.

Not sure its the best way...but it works.

Comment: So each frame you add a new callback? Also this code is compiled in the editor but will not be build able since EditorApplication belongs to the `UnityEdiror` namespace which is stripped of in a build

Comment: You are correct. I put UpdateRing() into Update and it works. 

I put Update() in a preprocessor statement to reduce the calls when running.

Comment: If later, I add the ability to make changes to the hierarchy in this class, will I then want Update to run during runtime?